# C++ Pointers Trace

Tags: c++

I make a trace and I get 20 as a result from a = a + deg1(&a); operation. But the result is 40. Could you guys explain it?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int deg1(int*p){
    *p = 20;
    int i = *p;
    return i;
}

int deg2(int x){
    return x * 2;
}

int main()
{
    int a = 10;
    a = a + deg1(&a);
    cout << a << '\n';
    int b = 20;
    b = b +deg2(b);
    cout <<b;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You are passing address of `a` to function. Function is evaluated first - function leads to `a` having value 20. Then `a` is added again to returned value (20) but `a` now has value 20 (function modified it). So the result is a = 20 + 20 = 40.

Answer (score 8):

The behavior is undefined. GCC indeed prints 40, but Clang prints 30.

In `a + deg1(&a)`, the read of `a` in the lhs is [unsequenced](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/eval_order) relative to the write to `a` in the function body.

Comment: The sum could be split into two instructions or be done with +=, or a separate variable be used to store the function side effect, to get the intended result.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not good at English

```
a = a + deg1(&a);
```

code execution order is like this

001524C9  lea         eax,[a]

001524CC  push        eax

001524CD  call        deg1 (01513A2h)  <- call deg1

001524D2  add         esp,4

001524D5  add         eax,dword ptr [a]  <- operator +

001524D8  mov         dword ptr [a],eax

a = a + deg1(&a)

first call deg1

then deg1 return 20 and make a = 20

therefore a = a + deg1(&a);

a = 20 + 20;

a = 40

Comment: This is one possible disassembly and one possible execution order, As @HolyBlackCat pointed out, the read of `a` can happen before calling `deg1`